# Unable to Import pyrfc in Python in Windows

Tags: python, saprfc, pyrfc

I am trying to connect python to SAP by calling the Function Module RFC_READ_TABLE. I followed every steps in [this link](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/09/connecting-python-with-sap-step-by-step-guide/), including setting up the environment variables.

[image]

However, when I try to Import Pyrfc, I got an error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pyrfc: The specified procedure could not be found.

[image]

If I set PATH=C:\nwrfcsdk\lib;C:\nwrfcsdk\bin;%PATH% manually in CMD Consule, it's working fine,

[image]

[image]

I have re-started my computer many times. Still the same issue.
Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: it may be related to the fact that you are running python through Anaconda in a virtual environment, that's why it does not "see" your pyrfc package. Try to install pyrfc in a clean Puthon

Comment: hello, many thanks for your advise. the thing is I installed pyrfc-2.0.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl file in the Anaconda 'Root' path, and it seemed successfully installed. did you mean i should install this whl file in a different location? //Felix

Comment: why don't you install it through pip? `pip install pyrfc --no-binary :all:`

Comment: I tried this, but still the same error. I have to set up environment variable manually in the CMD console: set PATH=C:\nwrfcsdk\lib;C:\nwrfcsdk\bin;%PATH%

Comment: try to install pyrfc 2.5. remove pyrfc 2.0

Comment: Please, do not paste text as image.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you downloaded the wrong version of PyRFC and that is why it cannot find it in the path:

https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC/issues/152

[image]

I got into this trap in the recent past and pulled my hairs out trying to figure out the cause why NWRFC/PyRFC is not recognized on my machine

Comment: thanks! I tried again to download the SKD 64bit version. still the same error. shall i call a teams meeting with u if it's possible?